# Status label with more info - how best to show the "more info" part?

Tags: error-message, status, alerts, uploading-documents

I have this one error status in a table. The "Learn more" is underlined, and that's how user knows to click on it, to learn how to troubleshoot the problem. When they click on "Learn more", they get this slide-out little panel, that tells them what to do.

I wonder if there are other patterns for this type of situation.

[image]

Comment: There are lots of different design patterns that relate to the progressive disclosure of information, whether it is to do with errors, table data and combinations thereof. You might need to think more carefully about what the requirements and specifications for your design system is before implementing a new pattern.

Comment: I'd echo @MichaelLai, and add that factors that will influence the pattern you choose will include things like the likely length of the text, whether there might be links/buttons inside that text, what devices the table will be displayed on, what conventions exist in other systems the same users might also be using, whether users might want to copy the text to the clipboard, etc. etc. I'm afraid simply asking us to provide a list isn't going to get you to a good design.